# Prove that any infinite set $B$ contains a denumerable subset (I need help to understand the author hint)

Tags: set-theory

The question is stated exactly as follows:

Prove that any infinite set $B$ contains a denumerable subset. (Hint: This requires the Axiom of Choice, which provides a function $f$ such that $f(D) \in D$ for all non-empty subsets $D$ of $B$. Define, by the Iteration Theorem, a function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow B$ such that $g(1) = f(B)$ and $g(n+1) = f(B - g(n))$. Then $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow B$ is a one-one function and $Range(g)$ is a denumerable subset of $B$).

The first thing which make me confuse in the question is that the author is using set difference operation with $B$ and $g(n)$, but $g(n)$ dont need to be a set, since B can be any infinite set, which probably include a infinite set of urelements.

If I interpreted the hint correctly I think the author wanted to define $g(n+1)$ as $f(B - \{g(n)\})$, but even in this case it will not imply in $g$ being a one-one function, because for every choice the unique element being excluded is the previous one, not all the previous.

Using the notation $\mathbb{N}_n$ to denote the subset of natural numbers from 1 up to $n$, I think we can redefine the function $g$ as follows:

$$g(1) = f(B)$$
$$g(n+1) = f(B - g[\mathbb{N}_n])$$

But Im not sure that its precise, but I think it captures the idea that the choice function will never peek a repeated elements and thus the function $g$ is one-one.

Maybe I just dont understood well what the author mean in the hint, I need help to clarify this, and I want to know if the Axioma of Choice is really needed to solve this question.

For reference, the book is Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis by Elliot Mendelson, it is the question 7 in Annex D.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605983/proving-every-infinite-set-s-contains-a-denumerable-subset). And yes, I think that the author means: remove from $B$ the element $f(1)$, and so on.

Comment: It have a prove in the question itself and a good answer to OP questions, but it do not include some discussion about the hint used by Elliot Mendelson and his definition of one-one function using iteration theorem.

Comment: The basic idea is to use the axiom of choice to repeatedly remove a non-selected element out. It does seem like there’s a typo in the question.  

To show this, you at the very least need the axiom of countable choice, which most mathematicians agree with.

Comment: Removing the image for the subset $\mathbb{N}_n$ of naturals "before the choice" in the definition as I tried, is correct?

I will need to take a look on the variations of AC, I still dont know what is the difference between them.

Comment: Yes that's correct. You want the $n+1$-st element to be chosen from B minus the previous $n$ choices.